# Does a goroutine pool make sense like thread pools in other languages?

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine

I build a simple `goroutine` worker pool with a few `chan` for a stream of events and it works totally fine. Due to the nature of `goroutines` I started to ask myself what I gain by doing that other then limiting the concurrent workers. The `gorutines` them self don't have any state they reuse per execution so that there would be value in keeping them around.

So the question is, does it even make sense to start `goroutines` and reuse them or just always create a fresh one and just limit the number possible to create/run at the same time?

Comment: This is too broad to give you a good answer. In general, goroutines are very lightweight, so there little advantage in re-using them. If you want to rate-limit how many things you're processing at once, it's easier to do with other mechanisms (plain counter) than a worker pool.

Comment: No it does not. The whole idea of coroutines is to get rid of the need of a pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a goroutine is an *executing function,* it can be thought of as comprising the set of the followng resources:

- The code it executes;
- The state the Go runtime scheduler maintains for that goroutine;
- The state which is *private to the goroutine.*

The latter is values a goroutine has allocated locally
(on its stack) and on the heap.

The code is shared;
the state in the scheduler has reasonably negligible cost
but the state a goroutine keeps *may* be costly to re-create.

The latter point may be used as a justification to keep goroutines
around in a pool.  But on the other hand, most of the time it's simpler
to pool the resources group of goroutines carrying out similar tasks
re-use — instead of the goroutines themselves.

Comment: The question states flat-out "the gorutines them self don't have any state they reuse per execution".

Comment: @Adrian, there's a neat thing I'm going to tell you flat-out: StackOverflow exists not only as a Q&A service but also as a platform where people can search for existing answers. Most use Google for that, but no matter how they search, that searching uses keywords to find relevant material. That's why—in my book—answering questions in a generic way helps. All-in-all, my answer provides enough general information to completely address the more narrowly-scoped original answer.

Comment: Gosh that is super neat, you're right! If you want to answer more than was asked, great! Just say something like "it looks like this may not apply to your current situation, but..." so that askers can easily tell which parts are answering their question, and which parts are just stuff you think someone might find useful some day.